# How do i make this functions update the quantity of an item if it already exists in the embedded schema and not add the item to the list?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I expect these functions to add an item to an embedded schema that serves as a cart in an e-commerce application and also update just the quantity when an item that already exists in the cart is added to it. My current implementation only adds items to the cart but does update the quantity when an item that already exist in the cart is added.

```
 def add_to_cart(%Order{line_item: []} = cart, cart_params) do
    attrs = %{line_item: [cart_params]}
    update_cart(cart, attrs)
  end

def add_to_cart(%Order{line_item: items} = cart, cart_params) do
    items = items |> Enum.map(&Map.from_struct/1)

    attrs =
      case Enum.find(items, fn item -> cart_params[:item_id] == item.id end) do
        nil ->
          %{line_item: [cart_params | items]}

        line_item = %{} ->
          updated = %{line_item | quantity: cart_params[:quantity]}

          Enum.map(items, fn i = %{id: id} ->
            if id == line_item.id do
              updated
            else
              i
            end
          end)
      end

    update_cart(cart, attrs)
  end

 def update_cart(%Order{} = cart, attrs) do
    cart
    |> Order.cart_changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove this:

```
Enum.map(items, fn i = %{id: id} ->
  if id == line_item.id do
    updated
  else
   i
  end
end)
```

Would it be helpful to use [Enum.group_by/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) to group the two scenarios, or can you only ever have one item in your cart?

```
cart_params = %{item_id: 1}
items = [%{id: 1}, %{id: 2}]

Enum.group_by(items, fn item -> 
  if cart_params[:item_id] == item.id do 
    :already_in_cart
  else
    :new_cart_item
  end    
end)
# %{already_in_cart: [%{id: 1}], new_cart_item: [%{id: 2}]}
```